# robocopy options to ignore OSX invisible files, or, dot_clean first?

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

I'm trying to copy ~8GB of files from a USB stick to a win7 system. The files on the USB stick appear to be coming from an OSX system (`.DS_Store` files and corresponding `._filenames` for each file). For what it is worth, the USB stick is formatted FAT32.

The main directory contains seven subdirectories with a total of 250+ subdirs and there is a total of some 2500+ files. When I drag and drop copy I get a "Destination Path Too Long" error msg:

[image: Destination Path Too Long]

When I use the cp command, I get similar `PathTooLongException` error messages (notably, more of them...?)

Using the [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) command and the /e option, I am able to successfully copy all the files without error:

`robocopy G:\SOURCE_FOLDER C:\Users\user\Desktop\DESTINATION_FOLDER /e`

Is there a way to copy all the files with robocopy but to exclude the `._` "meta" files and `.DS_Store` files? Or is it better to simply recursively delete them? After doing some more research, would it be a better idea to [dot_clean](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dot_clean.1.html) the files before copying them to a windows system? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Robocopy with the `/XA:SH` and the `/XD *.` flags to exclude hidden folder and files which should keep the dot files from being copied over.

Comment: @hiambo nice - had to look up what the [RASHCNETO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698323/what-attributes-does-rashcnet-refer-to) file attributes were... If I am reading that right `/XA:SH` e**X**cludes **A**ttributes that are **S**ystem and **H**idden and `/XD *.` e**X**cludes **D**irectories that end in a period - shouldn't that be `.*`?

Comment: I didn't have the ability to test and it was late after a 12 hour day at work so you might be right. My notes say *. but they may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Bo :) I used the command with the `/XD *.` option and it seems to have worked just fine (tho I didn't test a robocopy with `/XD .*`...) Am I correct in reading the powershell syntax that `/XD *.` is e**X**cluding **D**irectories whose names end with a period?

Comment: The "*" effectively stands for the path up to such folders.